# Adding a StructuredProperty to a Model in NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

(couldn't think of a better title :S )

So I've recently changed from db to ndb and i can't get one part to work. I have this tutorial model that has chapters, so I am using 'ndb.StructuredProperty' to associate the model Chapter to the tutorial.
I can create the tutorials and the chapter with no problems but i can't point the chapters to the tutorial.

The Tutorial Model:

```
class Tutorial(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    presentation = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    extra1 = ndb.TextProperty()
    extra2 = ndb.TextProperty()
    extra3 = ndb.TextProperty()
    tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    votes = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    chapters = ndb.StructuredProperty(Chapter, repeated=True)
```

The Edit Class:

```
class EditTut(FuHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...
        ...

    def post(self):
        editMode = self.request.get('edit')

        if editMode == '2':
            ...
            ...

        elif editMode == '1':
            tutID = self.request.cookies.get('tut_id', '')
            tutorial = ndb.Key('Tutorial', tutID)
            title = self.request.get("chapTitle")
            content = self.request.get("content")
            note = self.request.get("note")

            chap = Chapter(title=title, content=content, note=note)
            chap.put()
            tutorialInstance = tutorial.get()
            tutorialInstance.chapters = chap
            tutorialInstance.put()

            self.redirect('/editTut?edit=%s' % '0')
        else:
            self.redirect('/editTut?edit=%s' % '1')
```

Using this code the tutorial is created but i get this error:

```
tutorialInstance.chapters = chap
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chapters'
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling 'put()' on your chapter - StructuredProperties are stored as part of their containing entity, and there's little point saving them separately as well.

Comment: you're right but now i have a problem. I want to get an ID of a chapter (to pass it to a URL) but there is none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: with the help of @nizz,
changing

```
tutorialInstance = tutorial.get()
tutorialInstance.chapters = chap
```

to:

```
tutorialInstance = ndb.Key('Tutorial', int(tutID)).get()
tutorialInstance.chapters.append(chap)
```

worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused.  When using `StructuredProperty`, the contained object doesn't have its own ID or key -- it's just more properties with funny names in the outer object.  Perhaps you want a repeated `KeyProperty` *linking* the book to its chapters rather than having all the chapters contained *inside* the book?  You have to choose one or the other.

Comment: i just want a way to pick one specific chapter... i now there is no ID or Key, and that is my problem, i wanted to know the best way to identify it. But... from what I've been reading and the problems I've been having ... my design probably is all wrong. I'm going to create a new post explaining what i want to do and how i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a list... you need to append the object to the list

```
tutorialInstance.chapters.append(chap)
```

Comment: thanks that worked, but I still had to make the changes made in my answer

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id

get_by_id(id, parent=None, app=None, namespace=None, **ctx_options)
    Returns an entity by ID. This is really just a shorthand for Key(cls, id).get()

so, the thing that made the difference was converting tutID to integer, not changing the function used

Comment: class.. in your case Tutorial:

Tutorial.get_by_id(tutId) equals ndb.Key('Tutorial', tutId).get()

Comment: That way it doesn't work, i get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chapters'

Comment: As I explained above, the difference is the int(...) part... Probably when you created the tutorial the type of the id you passed was integer, not string, so you need to pass an integer to the id. So, Tutorial.get_by_id(int(tutId)) equals ndb.Key('Tutorial', int(tutId)).get() (which is pretty much the same thing as above)