# NDB Query for Key or ID of StructuredProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

I'm new in Python and Google App Engine and have problems to fetch specific data from Datastore by using NDB.

I want to count the results of a query, where a StructuredProperty has the given key/entity/id:

```
class MyData(ndb.Model):
    group = ndb.StructuredProperty(MyGroup)

    @classmethod
    def get_count_by_group(cls, entity):
        return cls.query(MyData.group.key == entity.key).count()
        #return cls.query(MyData.group == entity).count()
```

The given entity is the instance of a Model, so I can access key and the id. After the call it fails, because property key is not found for "MyGroup". 
The documentation of NDB Queries contains examples for using filter on class properties and it works in other functions but I don't know how to query/filter for "internal" properties of the Model like key or id.

Comment: StructuredProperties don't have keys - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14652433/5320906

Comment: So, I have to compare the properties of the StrcuturedProperty with the values of the entity? Or is there another way?

Comment: Add another property to the structured property that holds the key value and query against that?

Comment: But I say that group is a StructuredProperty of the model "MyGroup". If I add a field "key" to the model I would have two fields "key". Isn't that redundant? Or should I add a KeyProperty field to "MyData"?

Comment: You might want to explain why you want to query against a key of a structured property.  What meaning does that key have?  Until you explain that, I don't think we can help you.

Comment: I'm sorry. I actually want to query against the ID of the datastore entity which is auto generated and part of the key. I have the "entity" and by this I want all "MyData" results where group matches with this "entity".
Is StructuredProperty maybe by design wrong and KeyProperty better to have the reference to the specific group?